# ListView with BaseAdapter are not responding to OnLongClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

I know that there are some topics that talk about this behavior but I haven't see there a solution that I can use.

the problem is the following, I have a list view that uses a BaseAdapter which implement OnLongClickListener. In the GetView method I set each view's onLongClickListener to this - but the long click are not being captured at all. In addition, I set each item onClickListener to a different item that implement OnClickListener and it did catch the click event, when I tried to do the same thing with longClick events it still didn't catch the long click event.

a little code:

```
public class ListOfCustomersAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnLongClickListener
 {

...

public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    vi.setOnClickListener(item); // works
    vi.setOnLongClickListener(this); // doesn't works
}


}
```

The item is an instance of class that implement OnClickListener

EDIT 1:

the view vi is a FrameLayout that contains several views:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/selector_item"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <include
        android:id="@+id/details_container"
        layout="@layout/list_message_my_details"
        android:paddingRight="6dp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/details_container"
        layout="@layout/list_message_responder_details" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_message_margin_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_message_margin_right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="55dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/white"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/message_with_attached_channel_item_bottom_minus_padding"
               android:paddingTop="@dimen/message_with_attached_channel_item_bottom_minus_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/mobli_dark" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_seperator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@color/mobli_dark_20"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Edit 2:

public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    View vi = convertView;
    ItemType item = items.get(position);

    if (item.getType() == null)
        vi = new TextItemType(context, item);
    else if (item.getType() == 1)
        vi = new ColorItemType(context, item);
    else if (item.getType() == 2)
        vi = new BoldItemType(context, item);
    else if (item.getType() == 3)
        vi = new FlatItemType(context, item);


    vi.setTag(item.getId());
    vi.setOnLongClickListener(this); //doesn't work
    vi.setOnClickListener(item); // work
    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your adapter associated to any activity? Try to implement the listener in your activity and not in your adapter.

Comment: he is associated with my main huge activity and I don't won't here to catch the long click events

Comment: Ok! What is your vi in the code? Is it some component of the convertView?

Comment: So, if I understood, you have a list of items, and each of them corresponds to the FrameLayout that you've presented, right? But in the code you posted I see no relation between the convertView and the vi that you're assigning the listener. I don't know if you're already doing this in other part of the getView code, but it should be 'convertView.setOnLongClickListener(this)'. I'm sorry if you're already doing this, but I can't see another reason.

Comment: So I have no idea what's wrong. I've made some tests and they worked correctly. Could you post the complete getView code?

Answer (score 0):

it s better to add listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this); in your mainActivity